# Update Multiple Rows of One Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update multiple rows of one column like below

```
update persons set salary = (select salary from persons where name = 'John Smith') + 20000;
```

Here I want to increment all the `persons`'s `salary` by 20000 if `name` is *John Smith*. But I am getting error

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
********** Error **********

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE persons 
   SET salary = salary + 20000
WHERE name = 'John Smith';
```